# How to tell CMAKE to download some necessary header files (more precisely GLM math library) WITHOUT TRYING TO COMPILE THEM?

Tags: c++, opengl, download, cmake, glm-math

I am setting up a CMAKE project that uses a lot of *ExternalProjects*. To build one of them (CEGUI), I need to download the **GLM (OpenGL Math Library)**. This Library is **include only library**, which means that you mustn't compile it. There are some test that can be compiled but there is no need for them in my project (moreover, one of them do not compile properly and breaks the compiling chain).

What I would like, is to find a way to tell CMAKE to only download the project (GIT update etc) like it does normally using the ExternalProject_add() function, but without trying to compile it (which produces a FATAL ERROR), and install the INCLUDE files (which *are the library indeed*).

Is there a *download header files and install them* functionnality in CMAKE? Does anyone already have this problem with **GLM** header-library?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can avoid a configure and build step in [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/ExternalProject.html) by setting `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` and `BUILD_COMMAND` as empty strings.

As for installing - I generally don't bother.  I like to keep all third party sources inside my own build tree, and just refer to these in my own project.  However, you could probably make the install step in this case something like `cmake -E copy_directory ...`.

So the full command could be:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
    glm
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glm
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                    <SOURCE_DIR>/glm ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/installed/glm
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_INSTALL ON
    )
```

If you wanted to avoid the install step too, then also just set it to an empty string.  Then to get the GLM include directory (to be used in subsequent [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/target_include_directories.html) or [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/include_directories.html) calls), just do e.g:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
    glm
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glm
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    )
ExternalProject_Get_Property(glm source_dir)
set(GlmIncludeDir ${source_dir}/glm)

...

target_include_directories(MyTarget PRIVATE ${GlmIncludeDir})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I wanted. I have slightly modified it to point to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX instead of CMAKE_BINARY_DIR but it works out of the box.

Comment: @Danduk82 For me, `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` works just fine. But `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` throws the error of `dir does not   exist after file(MAKE_DIRECTORY)...`.